# Displaying a slide tutorial when app launches first time

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uinavigationcontroller, ios9

I have a UIScrollView that will display three images when the app launches for the first time.

Here's my issue: I'm seeing if it's the first launch from my `AppDelegate`, taking the user to a UIScrollView (not embedded in the `NavigationController`) and then to the initial view controller that would normally appear if it's not a first time launch.

What I would like is for the user to swipe through these three slides and then be taken to the root view controller. What's the best way to do this?

Problems i'm facing:

When I detect that it's a first time launch, I'm setting the UIScrollView as the root and going there, and then, after they've swiped through the brief tutorial, i'm segueing into my initial view controller. Problem is that my UIScrollView isn't embedded in the navigation controller which cause a problem and doesn't display the navigation bar on the main view controller. I don't see a reason to embed it into the navigation controller because it will be displayed just once.

Any help would be so immensely appreciated!

[image: My current storyboard]

The storyboard not connected to the navigation stack is the tutorial UIScrollView that gets set as the root if it's a first time launch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the navigation controller your app's root view controller.

Make the tutorial a *presented view controller*. Present it once when it's needed initially; when the user is done, dismiss it; and never present it again.

Comment: The navigation controller is my root view controller. I'm also not entirely sure how to go about doing the second part. I'd prefer not to embed it in the navigation controller because I don't want a navigation bar and want the images to take up the entire height of the screen.

Comment: Did you even read what I said? If you don't know what a presented view controller is, or what "present"/"dismiss" means, you can't program iOS, so maybe it's time to find out.

Comment: I did. But i'm kind of new to this. So if you wouldn't mind elaborating, throwing a code snippet or linking me to something.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will brush up. In terms of flow, should I check if it's the apps first time launch from my app delegate and then go to my initial view controller or should I go directly go to my initial view controller and check if it's the first time there since I will be displaying both the presented view controller and what will come after it if it's not the first launch. Sorry if this is kind of a dumb question. Thanks a lot Matt.

Comment: It's not dumb but it's been asked and answered here a zillion times before, so just search. _Please_ do some research / learning on your own.

Comment: Matt, in terms of flow, should I implement this logic from the app delegate? From my understanding, no.

Comment: I think I'd do it from the navigation controller's root view controller, i.e. the first view controller whose view the user would see otherwise. — You could in fact do it from the app delegate, though. It's tricky however because you cannot present a presented view controller until the view controller you are presenting _from_ is actually in the view controller hierarchy (and I think its view needs to be in the interface) — which sounds very much like a view controller event.

Comment: I implemented it from the navigation controller's root view controller which seems to work fine. I have a boolean value in my NSUserDefaults that checks if it's the first launch or not. If yes, I am presenting it from my viewDidAppear and not the viewDidLoad because it's not in the view hierarchy at that point. I hope all of that sounds good. I just want to make sure i'm following "best practice" although it seems the best practice is really dependent upon the apps requirements.